# Supabase `UPDATE requires a WHERE clause`

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I try to update a state of some rows in my table `game`. My table has a foreignkey `lobby` to the `lobby` table, that has a `name` and a `hash`.

I try the following in TypeScript:

```
supabaseClient
    .from("game")
    .update({ state: closedGameState })
    .eq("lobby.name", lobbyName)
    .eq("lobby.hash", lobbyHash)
    .select("lobby(name, hash)");
```

But I get this error message:

```
{
  error: {
    code: "21000",
    details: null,
    hint: null,
    message: "UPDATE requires a WHERE clause"
  },
  data: null,
  count: null,
  status: 400,
  statusText: "Bad Request"
}
```

I am setting two where-clauses. So what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Would you get the same error without the select statement at the end?